# Chrome Web Store app install redirects to a blank page

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I have a Google Apps Marketplace app with a Chrome Web Store entry. When installing the app from the Web Store using Chrome browser I always get redirected to a blank page with this URL:

https://apis.google.com/additnow/signin.html?applicationid=1234567890&callback=true&parenturl=https://chrome.google.com

This page comes after the OAuth permissions request page, and only appears when installing from Chrome browser. The app installs correctly though, I can see it in the Google Admin console and I am able to use it properly.

This is the Chrome Web Store manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "App",
  "version": "1.43",
  "description": "App Description",
  "icons": {
  "128": "icons/128.png",
   "16": "icons/16.png"
 },
 "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],
 "api_console_project_id": "1234567890"
}
```

Comment: We are experiencing the same problem.  I wish google support staff would at least comment on this issue.

Comment: We are having the same issue. Did you figure out the solution?

Comment: We have heard reports of this happening, but are having trouble reproducing it. Can you see if there are any errors thrown in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @EricKoleda, I'm running into the same exact issue and don't see any js errors.  I'd be happy to demo the issue for you in a private chat if you're available.

Comment: I've been able to replicate the problem on installs from the standalone page. Are you installing through the standalone page or the Admin console?

Comment: I'm installing from the standalone page by pressing on the "Integrate with Google" button.  The full URL I'm hitting is (w/ appId removed): https://admin.google.com/OauthTosCombined?appId=<myappid>&redirectUri=https://apis.google.com/additnow/signin.html?applicationid%3D<myappid>%26callback%3Dtrue%26parenturl%3Dhttps://chrome.google.com%26appfinder%3Dfalse

Comment: @EricKoleda Thanks for getting back to me on this.  Just adding an '@' to you so you see the previous comment about the specific behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow up with the team.

Comment: Sorry, nothing to report yet.

Comment: @EricKoleda Any updates on this?  It appears that the issue still exists.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change isn't always easy. Back in September, Google revamped the "New Tab" page in its Chrome browser -- and a lot of folks weren't too thrilled with the results.

The new "New Tab" page used to be easy enough to avoid: [A setting in Chrome's about://flags section](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2474978/internet/how-to-switch-back-to-chrome-s-old--new-tab--page.html) let you toggle back to the original "New Tab" setup with a flip of a switch. But this week's latest stable Chrome release removed that setting from the browser.

So what to do? If you're still not a fan of the new "New Tab" page, I have a new workaround that might be just what you need.

This one requires a third-party extension called [New Tab Redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna). It's free to use.

All you do is install the extension and then head into its settings (you'll be presented with a link immediately after installation). Click the option to have the extension set the Chrome Apps page as your "New Tab" page. Open a new tab, and voilà: You'll have something pretty darn close to the original "New Tab" setup.

Comment: Agree with this answer.