# Marketplace V2 install flow pops up blank page which must be dismissed before install continues

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have created an installable app for the new google apps marketplace and published it for select users testing. When I install the app from the listing, then the data access and terms of use dialog pops up and when I click 'Accept', then a blank page pops up which has the URL:

https://apis.google.com/additnow/signin.html?applicationid=xxx&callback=true&parenturl=https://chrome.google.com&appfinder=false

And install is blocked until I dismiss the blank page. Once I dismiss the page, then I get the next dialog that says the app has been added. We need this problem to be resolved.

**EDIT**

I have more information in case it is useful for google folks. The problem only occurs when using chrome and only if user is already logged into google before hitting the 'Integrate with Google' button to install from the listing. The problem doesn't occur in firefox. The problem also doesn't occur in chrome if the user is not logged in to google when hitting 'Integrate with Google' button such that the user will then be asked to log in before being taken to the data access and terms dialog.

Further when the blank page is being displayed there is a dialog being displayed under it. That says 'Get ready to install' '< app name > needs your permission in order to start installing.' and has two buttons Cancel and Continue. Cancel will dismiss this dialog, and Continue will not dismiss the dialog but keeps bringing up the blank page to the front. In either case, unless you dismiss the the blank page you don't get the dialog that says app has been added. [On further testing, the 'Get ready to install' dialog gets popped up immedately after hitting 'Integrate with Google'. It is already there (underneath) the data access and terms of use dialog.]

Lastly, I see that someone else has reported a similar issue:

[Chrome Web Store app install redirects to a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851369/chrome-web-store-app-install-redirects-to-a-blank-page)

Regards,
LT

Comment: I can confirm this. Happens to my app too. Though looks this popup has started auto closing in last few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

We got our listing reviewed by google and it now shows up under the list of google app marketplace apps that are shown in the google apps domain admin panel (admin.google.com) in Marketplace Apps. I'm finding that if I install from there then blank window does not pop up even when using chrome. The blank window still pops up when installing from the chrome webstore listing page using chrome.

LT

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  @user1452215, were you ever able to resolve this issue?  Thanks!