# Remote install of app from Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I'm in the process of migrating a Google App Engine / Java based app over to the new Google Apps Marketplace.

The old app enabled users to install the app without actually being on the marketplace page by leveraging a redirect URL extracted from a user click on the "Add It Now" button from the old marketplace page.  This URL triggers an account login button that is then followed up by the app install.  The URL was of the form:

https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/interstitialRedirect?domain&productListingId=&index=0&followup=https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/interstitialRedirect?domain&productListingId=&index=0&service=marketplace&passive=true&ul=1

I've tried using the redirect URL generated from clicking on "Integrate with Google" from the new marketplace page but it goes through the authorization page then leads me to a blank page (though the app is successfully installed).  The blank page issue is likely related to the following issue - [Chrome Web Store app install redirects to a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851369/chrome-web-store-app-install-redirects-to-a-blank-page#comment40343734_21851369)

The new URL is of the form:

https://admin.google.com/OauthTosCombined?appId=&redirectUri=https://apis.google.com/additnow/signin.html?applicationid%3D%26callback%3Dtrue%26parenturl%3Dhttps://chrome.google.com%26appfinder%3Dfalse

Has anyone been able to successfully enable this scenario?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One supported means of allowing an admin to install your Marketplace from a web site is the Integrate with Google button which may be worth considering ( https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/button?hl=ca ).

Does the install button from the Chrome Web Store standalone page not work correctly, or is it only when attempting to utilize the URL from the button on the page elsewhere? If the former is not working correctly, then it does sound like the linked to issue. Including the URL to the standalone Chrome Web Store page and an example of your app manifest would be helpful in identifying whether this is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  The install button leading to the blank page appears to be a separate issue which I'm following up on in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851369/chrome-web-store-app-install-redirects-to-a-blank-page.  As for the remote installation, our scenario involves enabling an admin to install the app from an email by following a link (which our app translates to the appropriate url in the backend) so I don't think embedding the 'Integrate with Google' button will work.  Do you know if there's an endpoint I can simply direct users to install?

Comment: Thanks so much for following up and helping to nail down the bug on the other thread. This feature does not exist. To make sure I fully understand the use case so that we can prioritize this, is this only to enable the redirect from the old marketplace page? Are there other cases where you are using this ability?

Comment: We have a workflow where we generate an install link that users can click on to install our app.  This functionality is used by 1) prospective customers from an email link and 2) by resellers of our app who can install the app onto their customers' domains through an internal dashboard we provide.  I'm hoping that once the blank page issue is resolved, this workflow will work using the URL we captured from clicking on "Integrate with Google".  Otherwise, a specific endpoint would be needed.